# Redirect/rewrite legacy URLs with nginx to an Angular app that requires the hash

Tags: angular, nginx, redirect, url-rewriting

I have a series of existing links to a legacy application that need to be handled by an Angular application which uses the hash URL format.

For example, a legacy URL like this:

```
example.com/downloads/anexistinguuid
```

Needs to be redirected in nginx to this:

```
example.com/#/downloads/anexistinguuid
```

I've tried the following:

```
   location /downloads {
        proxy_pass example.com/#/downloads/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
```

But that doesn't seem to be the right approach.

There are plenty of examples of how to remove the hash from the URL, but I can't change the URL strategy of the Angular app at this point and have to preserve compatibility with a number of links already in the wild that I also can't change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to redirect rather than reverse proxy.

Try:

```
location /downloads {
    return 301 /#$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: Absolutely brilliant - that's exactly what I needed - thank you!